# Как вставить в таблицу все значения из БД?

Tags: php, html

Вопрос в шапке

```html
<table>
            <tr>
                <th width="15%">ID</th>
                <th width="15%">Номер</th>
                <th width="15%">Адрес</th>
                <th>Проблема</th>
            </tr>
            <?php include 'assets/php/getTicket.php';?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['number']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['adres']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['problem']; ?></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

```html
<?php
    include 'db.php';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tickets`";
    $sendquery = $db->query($query);

    $row = $sendquery->fetchAll();
    $count = sizeof($row);
?>
```

Comment: необходимо написать цикл. И из бд получать ассоциативный массив, а не 0-индексированный

Comment: пример можно???

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php) возвращается не одна строка, а несколько. Следовательно нужен перебор маcсива:

```
$rows = $sendquery->fetchAll();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['number']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['adres']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['problem']; ?></td>
</tr> 
<?
}
```